# Read text from a pdf file which is generated using ghostscript (C#)

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, ghostscript

I have a requirement to read a specific text (account number) from pdf file. The pdf file is generated from a ps file and I fetch this pdf file and work on that. I tried multiple ways, but couldn't read the file.

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(@"C:\Sdrive\app_122312.pdf");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, 1));
richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
reader.Close();
MessageBox.Show("done");
```

This is what I use in my code. Any thoughts? Is this because of any issue with ghostscript generated file? Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you getting an exception?  What is it actually doing?

Comment: No exception at all.. it reads the file but nothing came in..

Comment: Verify that all of the fonts used in the PDF are installed on your system.

Comment: How do I know that?

Comment: Is this actually an image file converted to pdf?

Comment: You are going to have to share a copy of the file (or a dummy one with the same problem) before anyone can tell you much about it.

Comment: So this was the issue.. the pdf generated from the ghostscript is actually an image converted to pdf (Thats why its not readable with itextsharp or any other pdf generator/reader). So what I did is , I converted the pdf to an Image and tried to extract data with MODI and that worked well. I am not sure whether this is the exact way to do this, but at least  as a work around for the time being..